# python counting examples based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count in a dataframe how many examples have the same criteria. The criteria will be selected by me before counting the examples.

i want to use it with the groupby but i didn't find a solution

```py
df_education = df.groupby(['Education','Self_Employed',"Loan_Status"], axis=0).count()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try:

```py
df_education = df.groupby(
    ["Education", "Self_Employed", "Loan_Status"], 
    axis=0
).size()
```